# Set post_parent value for the images uploaded by Add Media button into post

Tags: uploads, wp-update-post, media-modal

I'm working on a front-end form plug-in and create shortcode to display front-end form on a page or post.

While I was testing, I found all image files uploaded by `Add Media` button which will be inlined in content will get `post_parent` value from the actual page/post that has my shortcode in it.

I want to update `post_parent` to the ID of newly created post that generated by my front-end plugin.

I'm assuming I can use

```
wp_update_post(
  array(
    'ID' => $att_id, 
    'post_parent' => $post_id
  )
);
```

But how I get all the IDs of images it will be inlined in content(Uploaded by Add Media button)?